# How to initialize array to 0 in C?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I need a big null array in C as a global. Is there any way to do this besides typing out

```
char ZEROARRAY[1024] = {0, 0, 0, /* ... 1021 more times... */ };
```

?

Comment: char ZEROARRAY[1024] = { 0 };

Comment: If you'll ever need to allocate memory on the heap, you can also use calloc(). For example char *zeroarray = calloc(1024, sizoef(*zeroarray)); .

Comment: N.B. calloc is fine for `char` etc, but if you want an array-of-pointers, you should set them explicitly to NULL, there is (absurdly!) no guarantee that NULL is represented as zero-bytes.  This even though the literal `0` implicitly represents the null pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Global variables and static variables are automatically initialized to zero. If you have simply

```
char ZEROARRAY[1024];
```

at global scope it will be all zeros at runtime. But actually there *is* a shorthand syntax if you had a local array. If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type. You could write:

```
char ZEROARRAY[1024] = {0};
```

The compiler would fill the unwritten entries with zeros. Alternatively you could use `memset` to initialize the array at program startup:

```
memset(ZEROARRAY, 0, 1024);
```

That would be useful if you had changed it and wanted to reset it back to all zeros.

Comment: {0}; works fine, C99 [$6.7.8/21]
If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration

Comment: Please refer to: The initialized 0 is not a `character`. it is a `integer`.

Comment: `{}` discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code `memset` is not obviously correct: I think it only works for 0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138188/set-all-bytes-of-int-to-unsigned-char0-guaranteed-to-represent-zero

Comment: If it's an array of structs, and using `-Werror=missing-braces` in gcc, it must be initialized to `{{0}}`. If the first struct element is an other struct  then`{{{0}}}` and so on. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434865/quickest-way-to-initialize-an-array-of-structures-to-all-0s

Comment: Today I encountered the weird ... `int arr[256]={1,2,7,{0}};` ... which brought me here.  Didn't even know this partial-zeroing was a thing until I saw it.

Comment: Note that char ZEROARRAY[1024] = {0}; initializes each element with character NULL of ASCII table not character 0. If you print ascii value of any of the elements of this array it will print 0(ascii value of character NULL) not 48 (ascii value for character 0)

Comment: Suggest cautioning against creating large arrays on the stack; 1024 is "borderline-large".

Comment: I don't like the -  char ZEROARRAY[1024];  - because non global arrays are not initialised and doing that can make you forget about that detail and get errors on arrays created later on.

Answer (score 56):

If you'd like to initialize the array to values other than 0, with `gcc` you can do:

```
int array[1024] = { [ 0 ... 1023 ] = -1 };
```

This is a GNU extension of C99 [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). In older GCC, you may need to use `-std=gnu99` to compile your code.

Comment: Designated initializers are standard in C99. The use of `...` to denote a range is a gcc-specific extension.