# What does {0} mean?

Tags: c

What does {0} mean below?

An array of one zero char? But I don't think you can initialize a larger array with a smaller array, or can you? And it would be int, not char, so would cause at least a warning, right? Or am I misunderstanding it completely? Does this result in buffer's first character being zeroed out?

```
struct ring_buffer
{
    unsigned char buffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile unsigned int head;
    volatile unsigned int tail;
};

ring_buffer rx_buffer  =  { { 0 }, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: `""` would have done the same job in this case.

Comment: The inner `{0}` seems really to be expressed more for the benefit of the reader/maintainer, making explicit what would implicitly already be the case if the entire RHS of the expression consisted only of `{0}`, instead of `{{0},0,0}`.

Comment: " I don't think" -- maybe think less and read the documentation more? "would cause at least a warning" -- do you expect `char c = 'x';` to produce a warning? `'x`' is an int in C.

Comment: @JimBalter, having a bad day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{0}` means "zero-init" this struct or array.  In the example above, rx_buffer.buffer will be filled with all zero bytes instead of whatever happened to be on the stack at that moment.

The following should also work for intializing the entire ring_buffer struct to all zero bytes:

```
ring_buffer rx_buffer = {0};
```

Comment: `{0}` also will initialize pointers to be null pointers, so it is a good way to initialize any variable at all (including arrays and structures).

Comment: "{0} means "zero-init" this struct or array" -- it's not a special case ... `{1}` means "initialize the first item to 1 and initialize the rest of the items to zero" -- unspecified initializers are always 0.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize an array in this format: `char array = { value1, value2, ...};`

In C, if array (or structure) length is larger than the number of values you used to initialize then compiler automatically initializes the rest of the values to `0`.

In the same way you can initialize structure also. In your case since the first element is an array it is initialized as an array to all `0`.

Therefore, to explain: `ring_buffer rx_buffer  =  { { 0 }, 0, 0 };`

This will declare a structure variable `rx_buffer` of type `struct ring_buffer` and initialize all its elements to zero. Since the first element is itself an array, it is initialized the same way a regular array is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It's mean zero init array  of uchar (all elements  0)
rx_buffer.buffer = {0}

Answer (score 0):

**But I don't think you can initialize a larger array with a smaller array, or can you?**

If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type

This may help you
[How to initialize array to 0 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589749/initialize-array-to-0-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a variable with {0} means to fill it with zeros. It is a way to explicitly show to a reviewer of the code that the variable is zeroed. Your initialization is a message to other developers not to the compiler because static variables without initialization are initialized to 0 by default.

However, if it was followed by non zero values, it would have different meaning. For example:

```
struct ring_buffer {
   unsigned char buffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
   volatile unsigned int head;
   volatile unsigned int tail;
};

ring_buffer rx_buffer  =  { { 0 }, 1, 2 };
```

would mean that `buffer` is filled with zeros, `head` is initialized to 1 and `tail` to 2.

Probably the author of the code supposed that one day the code may be changed in such a way and made this explicit in order to avoid possible bugs in the future.