# C++ How do I set an entire character array to blank spaces?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following declared variable:

```
char mychararray[35];
```

and I want to set every character in the array to a blank space...
How can I do that?

My instructor told me all I had to do was put

```
mychararray = "";
```

but that didn't work at all...

Am I using an outdated version of Visual Studio (2012), or is this just a bad initialization? If it is the latter, please explain how to make all the characters a blank space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [initialize array to 0 in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589749/initialize-array-to-0-in-c)

Comment: Assigning on one line `char myarray[35] = "";` does work. All characters will be `'\0'`.

Comment: @zenith Not really. It doesn't "set every character in the array to a blank space".

Comment: @juanchopanza I know. I was just pointing out the OP's `= ""` wasn't just some bad initialization.

Comment: Please clarify what a "blank space" is.  Do you want every character in the array to be a space character ' ' (with no terminating '\0'), or do you want them all to be '\0', or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can initialize it the way your instructor suggested as you declare the array:

```
char mychararray[35] = "";
```

It will set the array to an empty string.

If you want to make it an empty string later, then you can just do

```
mychararray[0] = '\0';
```

If you want to make it an array consisting of 34 spaces (35th character being null terminator), then

```
memset(mychararray, ' ', 34);
mychararray[34] = '\0';
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm guessing the first option would be closest to what my instructor was trying to get me to do, correct?

Comment: @tomkelley13 No, the first option does not set the entire array to blank spaces. It sets the first element to the null terminator. All other elements are left uninitialized.

Comment: @tomkelley13, it does the same thing as if you originally wrote `char mychararray[35] = "";` I updated my answer.

Comment: I used the second option, that seems to be working for me... thank you.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Are you sure? [dcl.init.string]/3 says `If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized.`

Comment: @AndyProwl My comment predates the edit. The first option became the second one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ah, I see. I take it back :)

Comment: This helped me get a string setup properly for output to an LCD on Arduino (Nano) platform.  I used memset() and set the last byte to \0.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That is not initialization, it's assignment. For initializing an array when declaring it, you can write:

```
char mychararray[35] = "";
```

If you already have an array and want to set it to zero, you can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    char c[35] = "Hello, world!";
    std::fill(std::begin(c), std::end(c), '\0');
    // c will contain only zeros now.
}
```

However, C-style arrays are not very popular in modern C++. Prefer using `std::string` (which you can clear using the `clear()` member function), or `std::array<char, N>` if you need the size to be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) is your friend.

```
memset(mychararray, ' ', 34);
mychararray[34]='\0';
```

If you want to initialize the array with all elements being `'\0'`, you have a neater way through [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
char mychararray[35] = {};
```

Comment: overwrites memory by 1 byte. (mychararray[35] = '\0')

Comment: The function `std::fill` is safer, the `memset` function should only be used with `bytes`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Agreed. This indeed was a `char` array specific answer. Since the byte being specified is a `char` literal, overflow isn't a worry.

Answer (score 3):

Although you could use `std::fill_n(array, 35, ' ')`, you're probably better of using an [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), the preferred string class in C++.  Don't have to care about zero-termination or anything.

```
std::string blanks(35, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't initialie `char` to `' '` (which has the ascii value 0x20, btw); in fact, array initialization without specifying what to use for initialization doesn't necessarily take place (arrays in local scope are left uninitialized).