# can use " int a = {0} " in C programe to init a array?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, scalar, braced-init-list

I found this code , when I compile it ,
the compiler tell me "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer" .
I know my platform is old .
but I want know that "unsigned int bValue = {0}" is a new way to init array ?

```
unsigned int bValue = {0};
uBlockSize = sizeof(bValue) / sizeof(unsigned int);
for (i = 0; i < uBlockSize; i++)
    bValue[i] = ui8Value << 24U |
    ui8Value << 16U |
    ui8Value <<  8U |
    ui8Value;
```

I want know that "unsigned int bValue = {0}" is a new way to init array ?

Comment: It should probably be `unsigned int bValue[SOME_SIZE] = {0};`

Comment: Have a look at "uniform initialization" in C++.

Comment: It's definitely _not_ an array. Clang was OK with `unsigned int bValue = {0};` but it appears to be synonymous with `unsigned int bValue = 0;`

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question is tagged C and it's just plain array initialization. The `sizeof(bValue) / sizeof(unsigned int)` trick also suggests that.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana the code doesn't compile: there's nothing "plain" about it.

Comment: This does not make sense. `bValue` is not declared as an array so of course the compiler complains about the indexing in line 4 `bValue[i]`. This has nothing to do with the initialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize array to 0 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589749/how-to-initialize-array-to-0-in-c)

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: right, I missed the tag.

Comment: Where did you find this snippet and have you copied it verbatim?

Comment: Has ```bValue``` been ```typedefed``` to something?

Comment: `{0}` is a *universal initializer* which is valid for *any* type and sets the object to zero

Answer (score 4):

You declared a scalar object of the type `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int bValue = {0};
```

That is it is not an array declaration and hence you may not use the subscript operator with the identifier `bValue`. And the compiler reports about this prohibition.

However you may initialize scalar objects with expressions optionally enclosed in braces.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces.** The initial value of the object is
> that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints
> and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the
> scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

That is the declaration itself is correct. Only it declares not an array but a scalar object.

You could declare an array for example the following way

```
unsigned int bValue[] = {0};
```

In this case `bValue` is an array with one element initialized by 0.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't compile (I tested the latest versions of clang, gcc and MSVC) because `bValue[i]` is not applicable to a scalar. `bValue` doesn't appear to be an array (maybe the original code looks different?); therefore, any attempt at indexing will result in compilation error.

As correctly pointed out by @nielsen, the [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589749/how-to-initialize-array-to-0-in-c) in itself is correct, although it's more often seen applied to arrays.